# I want a screen door to shut slowly the whole way

Tags: doors

My wife asked me if I could make the screen door shut slowly. It has two pneumatic closers, top and bottom. Google told me to turn the screw on them clockwise. I did. However, the door closes fast until the last 22 degrees or so then closes real slowly. The door has a glass pane currently for winter and the closers are pinned to the outermost hole.

Is this the nature of screen doors closing or are there better pneumatic closers that will close at the same slow speed the whole way?

My door is an Emco by anderson and the serial number appears to be A-915348 [image: EMCO By anderson picture]. However, I cannot get any results on that on the Anderson window search.

Comment: A proper closer setting should run slow most of the way, then fast for the last bit to make sure the latch engages. It sounds like you adjusted the wrong part of the cycle. Either you turned the wrong valve adjustment, or thus closer doesn't let you adjust them independently. Not having any information about the closers, I can't tell you which.

Comment: Please post the model number of your closers (or of the door if original parts)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft see edits

Comment: There's no model number in that photo (and information on the closers is far more relevant anyway).

Comment: @isherwood it seems that they only put serial numbers not model numbers. The labels on the closers are completely closed.

Comment: Well, either take keshlam's advice and revisit your adjustments, or replace the closers. They're all pretty standard these days and should be an easy swap.